# UIView size and UIWindow rootViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

In following the exercises of a popular book for iOS Development I came across a line of code I don't understand and can't find an explanation for, so I thought I'd post on this community for insight...

In a UIViewController the view is initialized like this:

```
-(void)loadView {
    [self setView:[[SomeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]];
}
```

On the application delegate the controller is set as the rootViewController like this:

```
SomeController *sc = [[TouchViewController alloc] init];
[[self window] setRootViewController:sc];
```

How is it that the view is set to a zero rect and yet it comes up fullscreen when the application runs?

My guess is that the rootViewController's view is set to the window's bounds by the window... but I have not been able to confirm this anywhere...

Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the “View Management” section of the [*UIViewController Class Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> If a view controller is owned by a window object, it acts as the window’s root view controller. The view controller’s root view is added as a subview of the window and resized to fill the window.